# How to reflect childChanges on tableView - IOS Swift Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have a tableview and would like to add childChange function to my tableview, but I have tried to do so, and instead updating the Child, my Tableview adds another row with the changed child, so I have one old valued row and new updated row listed in my tableview.

in my viewdidload I have defined my firebase reference and added two functions:

```
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("paris")
    fetchBars()
    refreshBars()
```

and have defined below viewdidload two functions:

```
    func fetchBars(){

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let bar = Bar.bar(from: snapshot) else {return}

        self.bars.append(bar)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
func refreshBars(){
    ref.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let bar = Bar.bar(from: snapshot) else {return}
        self.bars.append(bar)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

For me it would be helpful if I could make an observer of ChildAdded and ChildChange in the single function. 
Please help me and thank you in advance.

CellforRow:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestoCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerCell

    let bar = bars[indexPath.row]
    cell.RestName.text = bar.barName
    cell.RestAddress.text = bar.barAddress
    cell.RestImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: bar.barMainImage))
    cell.percentLabel.text = bar.percentage


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Instead of appending the bar in childChanged event, you need to update the existing array and reload only that row for tableView.
There must be something uniqueID of a bar, you need to identify the indexPath of the modified bar in your datasource array, replace that object with the newer one, and reload the tableViewRow with that indexPath only.

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic I have added my cellforRow code. If it possible maybe you can show me how I should implement that, please?:)  I am new to IOS Development tbh

Comment: will you please show me you Model Class which name is `Bar` so i can get better idea

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the row instead of adding a new one, first of all, you need to add a unique id  for the Bar class to use it to get the index of the row, it will be something like this:

```
func refreshBars(){
    ref.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let bar = Bar.bar(from: snapshot) else {return}
        // you need to find the index of the bar
        let index = self.bars.index(where: { otherbar in bar.id == bar.id })!
        // remove the old one
        self.bars.remove(at: index)
        // add the new one
        self.bars.insert(bar, at: index)
        // reload the row with fade animation
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you code. It does however insert the updated version of row with the replacement of the first row of the other bar, but it still keeps the old one at the bottom.